# concept question about dll

Tags: c++, dll, graphics

My boss asks me to create a dll file using C++. The dll file needs to do the following:

1. create a blank area in Window
2. create some simple shapes (for an
   example, a rectangle) on the blank
   area
3. control the locations of the shapes
   in the blank area

I am new to C++, so please correct me if my understand is incorrect
Dll is a binary file, does it allow to call other libraries to create the blank area?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the DLL should be called from some executable and the dll can also call other dll's functions. While creating a dll, you need to create an executable to test the dll, and you can use other dll by dynamically loading or using its .lib in the project.